# Create a Mention friend in iOS with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode8, ios10, mention

still learning iOS development, want to create something like mention friend likes in Facebook / Instagram.

[Mention People UI in Instagram](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/371x659q90/r/923/TdEWXS.png)

Is it using new TableViewController and add subview to the same View Controller? (in this case, CommentViewController) , but, when i already have UITAbleViewController in my CommentViewController, how can i handle the second tableviewcontroller?

Comment: if you use UITableViewController than i think it not possible, but if you use UITableView in UIViewController than you can do it with using Tag

Comment: "How can I handle..?" is not very specific, try to be more clear about what you have already done and what is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image you provided it looks as though the best way to implement this would be a UIViewController that has a UITableView added to it.  Each tableview that is created can have a delegate and datasource set for it.  When the textview detects that a mention is being entered (more about detecting this later) you would trigger a second tableview to appear as an additional view (subview) that overlays your current tableview (or as the accessory view of the keyboard, the way apple and others present a textview over the keyboard for text entry ex: messages app).

In order to manage the two tableviews my suggestion would be to create two additional classes each of which conform to the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewData source.  The first one would be the CommentsTableViewManager and the second would be the MentionsTableViewManager.  The first tableview would set the CommentsTableViewManager as its delegate and datasource while the second would use the MentionsTableViewManager.

The other problem you may run into later on is determining how to properly detect mentions being typed into the textview. I've actually created an open source library that will help you with this problem. It's located here: https://github.com/szweier/SZMentionsSwift the README should provide enough information for you to get started if you choose to use it.

I hope the information about helps get you started with your app.

Answer (score 0):

From architecture prospective it's way better to have a single table view with altered data source container, depending on current mode.

Speaking an instagram way - either you're showing comments, or, if `@` symbol was detected, displaying a list of users. So almost all your UITableView's delegate and data source methods will start with something like `if (isMentionMode)` and you'll choose specific cell class/cell's height/amount of rows per section/etc depends on `isMentionMode` state.